# Windows 10 Creators Update - Review privacy settings for your device

Tags: windows-10, privacy, windows-10-v1703

As part of Microsoft's rollout of the new [Windows 10 Creators Update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/features), some users are seeing notifications asking them to review their privacy settings before updating.

[image: Update prompt for Windows 10 Creators Update]

Clicking "Review settings" opens a page with 5 reviewable privacy options: **Location**, **Speech recognition**, **Diagnostics**, **Tailored experiences with diagnostics data**, and **Relevant Ads**. Each can be toggled 'On' or 'Off', with the exception of Diagnostics which can be set to 'Full' or 'Basic'

[image: Choose privacy settings for your device]

Is there a more detailed description of what each of these settings does?

*It's worth noting that if the initial prompt box is closed using "remind me later", there is no known way of manually making this screen reappear.*

Comment: What happens when you click "Learn more"?

Comment: The official Microsoft page titled [Choose your privacy settings for the Windows 10 Creators Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014916/windows-10-choose-your-privacy-settings-for-windows-10-creators-update) specifically says *"To learn more about each category and how they affect data transfers and usage, select **Learn more** at the bottom of the screen."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking "Learn More" displays a page with the following information.

> ### Intro
>
> When you set up Windows, we ask that you choose settings relating to
> your privacy. We recommend on the set-up screen the settings we
> consider appropriate to help make your device more reliable and secure
> while connecting to services, to give you a more personalized
> experience and to help improve our services. You can choose your
> settings now, or you can, as usual, update them any time by going to
> Start > Settings.
>
> The information below explains what data we collect and how it is
> used, depending on the settings you choose. Please be sure to review
> the full Microsoft Privacy Statement for more information on all the
> personal data we collect and how it is used when you use Windows (type
> aka.ms/privacy into any browser window to do so). The data we collect
> is sent to and stored in the USA and other countries as set forth in
> the Microsoft Privacy Statement.
>
> ### Location
>
> Microsoft’s location service provides location information to Windows
> devices using a combination of global positioning service (GPS),
> nearby wireless access points, cell towers, and your IP address,
> depending on the capabilities of your device.
>
> Turning on Location enables certain apps, services, and Windows
> features to ask for permission to access and use your location data to
> deliver location-aware services at as precise a level as your device
> supports. When your location is used by a location-aware app or
> service, your location information and recent location history is
> stored on your device and sent to Microsoft in a de-identified format
> to improve location services.
>
> In addition, if you are logged in with your Microsoft account, your
> last known good location information is saved to the cloud and
> available to other apps or services using your Microsoft account
> across your devices. If your device cannot obtain a good location on
> its own (like for example in a building or basement), it can use your
> last known good location stored in the cloud.
>
> You can turn off location access and clear your device’s location
> history at any time in Start > Settings > Privacy > Location.
>
> If you have a portable device, such as a laptop, turning on location
> will also enable the Find My Device feature, which uses your location
> data to help you find your device if you lose it. For this feature to
> work, you must log into Windows with your Microsoft Account. You can
> turn this off at any time in Start > Settings > Update & security >
> Find My Device.
>
> ### Speech recognition
>
> Windows provides both a device based speech recognition feature
> (available through the Windows Speech Recognition Desktop app), and a
> cloud based speech recognition service that was introduced alongside
> Cortana in those markets and regions where Cortana is available. To
> learn what languages and regions speech currently supports, search for
> “Cortana’s regions and languages” in any browser, or in the search
> bar. Turning on the Speech recognition setting allows Microsoft to
> collect and use your voice recordings to provide you with cloud-based
> speech recognition services in Cortana, supported Store apps, and over
> time in other parts of Windows. As part of that service, we also
> collect information from the user dictionary created on your device.
> This user dictionary stores unique words like names you write, which
> helps you type and ink more accurately. Both the voice data and the
> user dictionary are used in the aggregate to help improve our ability
> to correctly recognize all users’ speech. You can turn this off at any
> time in Start > Settings > Privacy > Speech, inking & typing. If you
> later allow Cortana to access information such as calendar and
> contacts data, your speech recognition experience can be personalized
> so that it works better for you. Note that you can always use
> device-based speech recognition by typing “Windows Speech Recognition”
> in the search bar and running the Windows Speech Recognition Desktop
> app.
>
> ### Diagnostics
>
> As you use Windows, we collect diagnostics data that helps us identify
> and troubleshoot problems and keep your devices up-to-date and secure.
> Depending on the settings you choose, diagnostics can also help us
> improve our products and services and provide you with personalized
> experiences. This data is transmitted to Microsoft and stored with one
> or more unique identifiers that can help us recognize an individual
> user on an individual device and understand the device's service
> issues and use patterns. There are two levels of diagnostic data: Full
> and Basic.
>
> Basic data is data that is vital to the operation of Windows. It
> allows us to know the capabilities of your device, what is installed,
> and whether Windows is operating correctly to help us keep Windows and
> apps secure, up-to-date, and running properly. This option includes
> basic error reporting back to Microsoft.
>
> Full data includes everything collected with Basic data, plus data
> about app usage, browser usage, how you use certain features or apps
> and for how long, which apps and features you use most often, how
> often you use Windows Help and Support, and which services you use to
> sign into apps. At Full, Microsoft collects additional diagnostic data
> including the memory state of your device when a system or app crash
> occurs (which may unintentionally include parts of a file you were
> using when a problem occurred). Any identifying information will be
> removed from your typed and handwritten input, such as words or
> characters. We use all this additional data in the aggregate to
> improve Microsoft products and services for all users.
>
> For both levels, we don’t use this data to personalize Microsoft
> products or services unless you let us do so with the separate
> Tailored experiences setting with diagnostic data (described below).
>
> You can adjust your diagnostic data collection level at any time in
> Start > Settings > Privacy > Feedback & diagnostics.
>
> ### Tailored experiences with diagnostic data
>
> If you choose to turn on tailored experiences, we will use some of the
> usage data described above in Diagnostics to personalize your
> experiences with Windows and other products and services. This
> includes suggestions on how to customize and optimize Windows; and
> recommendations and offers of Windows features and supported apps,
> services, hardware, and peripherals. For example, to help you get the
> most out of your device, we may tell you about features you may not
> know about or that are new. If you are having a problem with your
> Windows device, you may be offered a solution. You may be offered a
> chance to customize your lock screen with pictures, or to be shown
> more pictures of the kind you like, or fewer of the ones you don’t. If
> you are streaming a movie in your browser, you may be recommended an
> app from the Store that streams more efficiently. Or, if you are
> running out of space on your hard drive, Windows may recommend you try
> the OneDrive online storage service, or purchase more space if you
> need it. The scope of usage data will depend on whether you choose
> Full or Basic Diagnostic reporting. For example, if you choose Full,
> your data will include browser and app usage. However, even if you
> enable Tailored experiences, we will not use your crash, speech,
> typing, or inking input data for personalization. You can turn this
> off at any time in Start > Settings > Privacy > Feedback &
> diagnostics.
>
> ### Relevant ads
>
> Windows generates a unique advertising ID for each user on a device,
> which application developers and advertising networks can use to
> provide more relevant advertising in apps. When the advertising ID is
> enabled, apps can access and use the advertising ID in much the same
> way that websites can access and use a unique identifier stored in a
> cookie. Thus, your advertising ID can be used by app developers (and
> the advertising networks they work with) to provide more relevant
> advertising and other personalized experiences across their apps. You
> can turn this off at any time in Start > Settings > Privacy. Please
> note that turning advertising ID off will not reduce the number of ads
> you see, but it may mean that ads are less interesting and relevant to
> you. Turning it back on will reset the advertising ID.
>
> ### Windows Defender SmartScreen
>
> Windows Defender SmartScreen sends data to Microsoft about the
> websites you visit and files you download to warn you and help protect
> you and your device from unsafe web content or malicious software.
> Since we strive to protect you when using our services and those of
> third parties, we turn Windows Defender SmartScreen on by default. You
> can turn Windows Defender SmartScreen off at any time in Start >
> Settings > Privacy.

Answer (score 0):

To manually make that screen reappear, simply open the notification at the bottom right, and select the words under Update and Privacy settings.